# Node JS Insert text from file to name result file from Puppeteer scrap

Tags: javascript, node.js, linux, puppeteer

I am hacking together a node script in Puppeteer where I scrap a webpage and safe the content as a text file where I name the file after the date and want to add text from a text file at the end of the name.

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const fs = require('fs');

let utc_date_string = new Date().toLocaleString("en-US", { timeZone: "UTC" });
let date_utc = new Date(utc_date_string);
let year = date_utc.getFullYear();
let month = ("0" + (date_utc.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);
let date = ("0" + date_utc.getDate()).slice(-2);
let hours = ("0" + date_utc.getHours()).slice(-2);
let minutes = ("0" + date_utc.getMinutes()).slice(-2);
let time_hh_mm = hours +  + minutes;
let data = fs.readFileSync('insert.txt', 'utf8');

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch(
{
    headless: true,
    args: ['--single-process', '--no-zygote', '--no-sandbox']
  })
  const page = await browser.newPage()
await page.goto('https://example.com/xxx.html')
  const myproblem = await page.$eval('table', table => table.innerText)

fs.writeFile('/var/www/mydomain.com/xxx/'+year+'-'+month+'-'+date+'-'+time_hh_mm+'-'+data+'.txt', myproblem)
  await browser.close()
})()
```

This works so far but the problem is that the file name comes out like this

```
'2022-02-13-1453-test_text_insert'$'\n''.txt'
```

and not like this

```
2022-02-13-1453-test_text_insert.txt
```

If I use only the date, the file name comes out as expected.
I don't know from where the extra characters come from (they are not in the text file) or if there is something wrong with the code.

Comment: 1. Some piece of code has disappeared 2. You should consider using [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Comment: I checked the code, nothing has disappeared. Maybe something is missing what I don't know.

Comment: your code is broken, i've edit some lines, please recheck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

String error. You should check this line:

```
let time_hh_mm = hours +  + minutes;
```

Maybe it should be like this: (?)

```
let time_hh_mm = hours + minutes;
```

And you tried to read the file which contain the breakline character `\n`, you can try to trim it.

```
fs.writeFile('/var/www/mydomain.com/xxx/'+year+'-'+month+'-'+date+'-'+time_hh_mm+'-'+data.trim()+'.txt', myproblem)
```

Comment: made the change, it is still running but with the same result

Comment: try to debug by `console.log(data)`, or consider to check the file `insert.txt`, maybe it's broken or has breakline `\n` character inside, you can trim it `data.trim()`

Comment: This did the trick and the file name is correct. Thank you!

Comment: please select my answer as right and my pleasure.